# How to add NSmutable Array Values to NSarray

Tags: nsarray

Iam pretty new to Objective c,Iam unable  to add NSmutable array contents to NSarray here.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

    markarry=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

HolidayAppDelegate *delegatObj = (HolidayAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

for (int i=0;i<[delegatObj.Datearray count]; i++) {

    NSString *Str=[delegatObj.Datearray objectAtIndex:i];


    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd-yyyy"];

    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
            NSDate *dateFromString;
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:Str];


    [markarry addObject:dateFromString];
    [dateFromString release];
    [Str release];

}


 }
```

I need to add markarry contents to the nsarray.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Simple

```
NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:markarry];
```

**UPDATE**

Ok it seems your string is nil when you create it using dateformatter. Try to debug your app you will find the solution.[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd-yyyy"]; the format you are using here mmust be same as the string as. Otherwise you will get nil in your dateFromString object.

Comment: [dateFromString release]; [Str release]; comment these two lines. you are releasing an autoreleased object. You should not release an object which is already in autorelease pool.

Comment: ok I deleted those lines and have kept [dateformatter release].still it is crashing.

Comment: Rahul Iam not getting the contents of markarray into the newarray.nsarray returning null

Comment: I have checked on console and Nsdateformatter returning exact dates.No nil here

Comment: I have checked it is not returning nil.

Comment: have you checked your array after adding date to array? Try NSLog(@"Array count %d",[markArray count]); see if the array contains object or not. If array is filled with objects then you will defiantly  get the NSArray from markArray. Otherwise send me code I'll do it and send it back to you.